# Running image upload on WP Metabox Custom Image Loader

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using WP 4.9.4, I am trying to generate a image upload input in custom metabox by using this code inside the Metabox

```
<p>
    <label for="your_fields[image]">Image Upload</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="your_fields[image]" id="your_fields[image]" class="meta-image regular-text" value="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>">
    <input type="button" class="button image-upload" value="Browse">
</p>
<div class="image-preview"><img src="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>" style="max-width: 250px;"></div>
```

and in JavaScript I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
      var meta_image_frame;
      // Runs when the image button is clicked.
      $('.image-upload').click(function (e) {
        // Get preview pane
        var meta_image_preview = $(this).parent().parent().children('.image-preview');
        // Prevents the default action from occuring.
        e.preventDefault();
        var meta_image = $(this).parent().children('.meta-image');
        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if (meta_image_frame) {
          meta_image_frame.open();
          return;
        }
        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
          title: meta_image.title,
          button: {
            text: meta_image.button
          }
        });
        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function () {
          // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
          var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
          // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
          meta_image.val(media_attachment.url);
          meta_image_preview.children('img').attr('src', media_attachment.url);
        });
        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open();
      });
    });
```

But I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frames' of undefined
>
> error at Seting up the media library frame at
>
> ```
> meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({...});
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just figure it out that not having `'editor'` in Custom Post Type  support causing this issue but the point is I do not need to  have the editor enabled on this specific post type. Can you please let me know how I can fix this without having  the editor?

Comment: does anyone has any idea on this please?